# What is the process to log Hazelcast Near Cache hit/miss in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast, near-cache

How to log Hazelcast Near Cache hit/miss in my spring boot application?

I tried going through the documentation of Hazelcast but couldn't find anything related to this.

Do I need to implement this manually? Or does Hazelcast provides this functionality out of the box?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: IMap api has getLocalMapStats method, the returned object from this method has getNearCacheStats method, with it, you can see hit/miss.